# Set Picasso image as ListView Background

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, picasso, android-background

I am using Picasso library to load images stored on my server to my android application.
I am using the normal code to do this.

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

but now i want to set this image as a backgroud to my listview with `id = myList` .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you. :D

Answer (score 3):

You could try to override the `new target()` implementation to set your view.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(new Target() {
        @Override public void onSuccess(Bitmap bitmap) {
          // Set imageview bitmap here.
          // Do other stuff.
        }

        @Override public void onError() {
        }
      });
```

Please take note that the above won't work inside a ListView unless you implement hashCode/equals in your Target.

Comment: I will certainly try this and respond to you. Thank you :D

Comment: The `Target` will be garbage collected if you do this. Implement the interface on a view holder or `View` subclass directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was just looking into that interface as well.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the `Target` class.

Pseudo code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(...).into(
    new Target() {

    public void onLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
        mListView.setBackground(bitmap);
    }

    /* ... */

    }
);
```

Note that this code will *not compile*, as I don't know the exact API's, but this will help you further.

Comment: I will certainly try this and respond to you. Thank you :D

Comment: The `Target` will be garbage collected if you do this. Implement the interface on a view holder or `View` subclass directly.